# How to put About us and fedback dialog in wp8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to put About us and fedback dialog in wp8 application. I want the user to click on an icon and see the about us descrption and able to give feedback also.

Comment: Have you tried Googling or Bing-ing?

Answer (score 0):

For review =>

```
    MarketplaceReviewTask marketplaceReviewTask = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
    marketplaceReviewTask.Show();
```

For the about page, create basic page and put what do you want in.

Comment: please give me detailes  answer where to give the about.xaml and  what to write in App.xaml  .

Comment: About.xaml mock doesn't not exist. If you want to create an about page, you need to create page. Maybe i don't understand your "aboutpage" what do you mean?

Comment: About means   where I can give descripton about the app and apps manfucturer etc and the feedback means where the users can give the feedback or  response.